# How to customize the gradle error message from javacompile error

Tags: java, android, gradle, javac

We want to custom or change the error log of JavaCompileTask. 
We used a special java source location **"build\intermediates\merged\main\java"** which contains some processed java code that generated before JavaCompileTask executing.Now, when the task compile error and it prints the source code path start with  **"build\intermediates\merged\main\java"**. We want to replace the "build/**" preifix with original source code , then we can click the console link and jump to the correct file.

Gadle 3.5, AndroidPlugin 2.3.3 Jdk8

The console is showing the code path which was not what we wanted.

> D:\m4399_GameCenter\app\build\intermediates\merged\main\java\com\m4399\gamecenter\plugin\main\models\shop\ShopExchangeRecommendAppModel.java:29: error: ShopExchangeRecommendAppModel was not abstract, and not override method getTorrentId() of IAppDownloadModel

We want to format it to :

> D:\m4399_GameCenter\app\src\main\java\com\m4399\gamecenter\plugin\main\models\shop\ShopExchangeRecommendAppModel.java:29: error: ShopExchangeRecommendAppModel was not abstract, and not override method getTorrentId() of IAppDownloadModel .